# GsonBuilder cannot be found in JavaFX + Maven project's runnable jar

Tags: eclipse, maven, javafx, jar, gson

### Background

I'm developing a Maven project + JavaFX in Eclipse.
My application uses Gson for serialization.

Of course, when you haven't included Gson.jar then Eclipse will complaint that `GsonBuilder` (or any part of gson library for that matter) cannot be found.

I included the library through Maven dependency

After this, Eclipse is cool and I can import `GsonBuilder` (or any part of gson library for that matter).

Everything is good.

And `mvn clean install` works with no error.

### The Problem:

I go to `target` directory and execute `java -jar myapplication.jar`

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/GsonBuilder
at app.MyApplication.<clinit>(MyApplication.java:68)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplicationWithArgs$153(LauncherImpl.java:352)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$46/683287027.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/254413710.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/1171144110.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/553264065.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 13 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:383)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
... 5 more
```

So, can you please help me out here? What's happening and how can I fix this?

Why is it not detected? I mean, the compiler compiles without error. So, `gson` must be there.
I also tried to exclude and reinclude the library. No result.

Comment: How do you package your JAR? Maven doesn't include the dependencies in a normal JAR build, you have to use e.g. the maven-assembly-plugin to build a JAR with all dependencies in it.

Comment: Can you please add the contents of `pom.xml` to the question?

Answer (score 0):

@dunni is right.

I used `maven-jar-plugin` instead `maven-assembly-plugin`.

After adding my `pom.xml` with

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>my.main.class</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Then, execute:

`mvn clean compile assembly:single`

`mvn install`

there is an executable jar with postfix `jar-with-dependencies` in `target` directory.

Afterwards, executing `java -jar target/myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar` works like a charm.